# SettingWithCopyWarning occurs when using Pandas extract() within a function

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas I'm trying to filter my DataFrame by date, followed by extracting a reportId string (i.e. 6 digits between dashes) from a longer string; however, when I run the below code I get the warning:

SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
list_date = [1632309961, 1632310980, 1632311134, 1632411137, 
            1632411139, 1632411142, 1632411144, 1632411146, 
            1632413166, 1632413427]
list_id =   ['se-84c735-hg5675', 'se-5f73s9-hg3465', 'se-1f34g6-hg3455', 'se-09f67s-hg5123', 
            'se-5g63g9-hg1235', 'se-47h8h0-hg5555', 'se-h901h3-hg6755', 'se-287n54-hg5321', 
            'se-g357a8-hg6675', 'se-56q89r-hg5767']

df = pd.DataFrame([list_date, list_id], index=['date_unix','id']).T

def test_extract(df):
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_unix'], unit='s')
    df = df[df['date'] >= pd.to_datetime('2021-09-23')]
    df['reportId'] = df['id'].str.extract(r"([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})")
    return df

test_extract(df)
```

I've tried a few different fixes like making my date filter using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] or throwing .copy() after everything; however, I get the same issue:

```
def test_extract(df):
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_unix'], unit='s')
    df = df.loc[df['date'] >= pd.to_datetime('2021-09-23'),:]
    df['reportId'] = df['id'].str.extract(r"([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})")
    return df
```

Strangely, when I run this same code outside of a function I no longer receive the warning.  Can anyone provide me with a solution for avoiding this warning while the code is in the function?

Info:
Pandas - 0.23.4 :: Python 3.7.10 ::
OS - Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to this issue; however I'm still unsure of why this solution works but not others.  I simply moved the Pandas regex extraction before the date filter.  It makes sense that df['reportId'] is no longer being created from a copy of a slice, but I still don't know why formatting the date filter with .loc didn't solve this.  If anyone has insight I welcome your comment.

```
def test_extract(df):
    df['reportId'] = df['id'].str.extract(r"([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})")
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_unix'], unit='s')
    df = df[df['date'] >= pd.to_datetime('2021-09-23')]
    return df

test_extract(df)
```